# Consolidating multiple tables into a single form (datasheet view)

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I have 7 or 8 different tables, all of which store different information and all of which are linked to the Core table in some way.

Core contains name, SSN, stuff like that. Then I have a table for contact information, one for their addresses and others for various grouping purposes.

I want to consolidate all of these tables onto one datasheet to act as a sort of Master Editor. So instead of always using the front-end we've designed, mass edits can be conducted using the datasheet.

I'm having trouble with executing this desire. There are two primary problems I'm running into:

1. Not all records are being presented in the massive query I'm trying to run. It's only selecting records which have zero null values. So I tried to remove referential integrity between the relationships to see if that worked - it didn't. Now nothing is being queried.
2. I can't perform enough left joins. I thought I may try left instead of inner joins to see if the data would pull. I get an error message saying that the event can be run because the order in which the statements are to be run is too ambiguous.

Absolutely lost as to what my options are here. Maybe someone can give me a concept or somewhere else to start looking?

Comment: Possible problem 3: In order to end up with an editable datasheet, all of the relationships between all tables used in the query must be one-to-one. If even a single one is not, you will not be able to edit any of the information in the datasheet. [See article](http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html).  I bring this up because addresses in a single table could mean that spousal records in the core table could require a one-to-many relationship with addresses. As for your two stated issues, it's hard to recommend much without knowing what the query looks like.

Comment: You are simply getting your joins wrong. What you are describing is pretty much standard database stuff so unless you have some very weird relationships (maybe cyclic or many-to-many) the reason it is not working is that you are not doing it right. There is no limit to the number and type of joins you can perform, at least not one that you can reach with 7 or 8 tables. Don't try to do it all in one go. Start with just two tables and add one at a time.

Comment: @SunKnight0 I'm sorry what do you mean start with two and add one at a time? Is there a way for me to nest these queries within one another? Say start with tables 1 and two and make that query a block, then add table 3 to that block to form block 2, then table 4 to that to form block 3 and so on? Conceptually it makes sense but I have no idea how to write that SQL

Comment: Of course there is. You can create queries. It is not necessary to have a separate query for every step of the way, but queries is where you can test and troubleshoot all your joins. Once you get a query that has all the data you want, use it as your recordset. Use the GUI, don't write SQL. Test each step, each new table added. If you are actually trying to do the joins by writing SQL, no wonder it fails. I do databases for 20 years and I still have a hard time with multiple joins in Access SQL. It's parenthesis hell.

Comment: @SunKnight0 I had no idea that the Show Tables dialog in the design view allowed you to add pre-existing queries. That solved my problem. I just wrote a query for the first few tables and then when things got sketchy I just joined other tables onto those queries. I'm sure that's not efficient, but it works for now.